# Const Class and member functions

Tags: c++, function, class, member-functions, function-qualifier

Do you need to define const functions when you want to create a new const instance of a class?

Somehow my compiler dont find the "regular" (not const) functions, when i try to access them from a const class instance.

Comment: can you please add your code sample what you are trying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if an object is `const`, you can only call `const` functions on that object.

If a function is not marked `const`, the compiler must assume that it is allowed to change the members of the class.  And since you can't change the members of a `const` class instance, you cannot call non-`const` functions on that instance either.

Note that the opposite case is different - there is no problem calling `const` functions on non-`const` objects.  Therefore it is recommended to *always* mark member functions as `const` wherever it makes sense to do so.  It is important to mark function parameters, reference variables, etc. as `const` for many of these same reasons.  The community typically refers to this practice as maintaining "const correctness."